# How do you rename a Plunker project?

Tags: plunker

I have a plunker project that I am working on that is currently called "Untitled".  How do I change that?

I have updated the title tag in the head of the index file, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to save the project and add a title and tags, then you will be able to modify it again in the left side menu (Project Settings).

Comment: There are no project settings on the left side. I have added tags and a description and it's saved to "My plunks".  But there is no way to change the name "Untitled".